# After upgrade to Angular 6/Material 6 why am I facing 'mat-input-container is not a known element'?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular6

Below code was running fine before I upgraded to 6. Not sure what changed in between! I have required modules imported as well

```
MatInputModule,
MatSelectModule,
MatFormFieldModule

  <mat-input-container>
    <mat-select placeholder="Sort By" formControlName="sortBy">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let sortByObject of sortByList" [value]="sortByObject.value">
        {{ sortByObject.label }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-input-container>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This CSS class has been removed beginning version

> 6.0.0-beta.5 (2018-03-23)

**mat-input-container** has been deprecated, instead use **mat-form-field**

For details of breaking changes in 6.0.0-beta.5:

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-beta5-2018-03-23

For details of breaking changes in general, refer:

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 7):

As per https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview we are now supposed to use mat-form-field

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select">
      <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```